# Why doesn't my non-greedy match work in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

```
This  is  test
```

There are two tabs (\t) in this line. I want to get rid of the part from the beginning to the first tab key, which is "This ", and I used the following pattern:

```
:s/.\{-}\t//g
```

It says it can't find the pattern. If I use the following, both tabs are replaced, which isn't what I want. Why doesn't the first pattern work?

```
:s/.*\t//g
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>Your first attempt does not work because you are matching the fewest number of any character followed by a tab.  The fewest number of any character is zero (0).  So both of your tabs match without any other characters.</del>

Based on the comments, the above explanation was incorrect.

Here is one possible solution.

```
:s/^[^\t]*\t//
```

This goes from the beginning `^`, capturing any number of non-tab characters `[^\t]*` until it reaches a tab `\t`.

Comment: You don't need the `/g` flag here; it's only a single match from the beginning.

Comment: With apologies in advance, I'd like to point out that to my understanding your explanation of why it does not work is incorrect. First, because the question example _does_ work (removing the _g_ flag, of course). Second, _"you are matching the fewest number of any character […] and the fewest is zero"_ — no, that's not how it works. The engine tries to match `.` and it does on first character of the line. Then proceeds in a ungreedy fashion until the tab which is enforced by `\t`. It does not reset the match start just to match as few as possible. This is a common misconception.

Comment: @sidyll, you are right about my explanation of why it did not work.  Thanks for taking the time to read it, and correct me.  Your answer should be selected as the correct one.

Comment: Please feel free to edit and adapt your answer. You should keep the alternative example as well, it's always good to have multiple solutions!

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern `/.\{-}\t` didn't work because of the `g` flag in the `:s` command. This flag enables global matching so it matches twice. Just remove the flag and it will work. In addition, when deleting something you can omit the *replacement* part in `:s`:

```
:s/.\{-}\t
```

The full `:s/.\{-}\t//` is fine as well. Note that in either case it should not say "pattern not found" as you described. If you see that message, there is something else different between your example and your actual text.

Comment: Could you explain why this doesn't work for the _last_ tab?  That is, `:s/\t.\{-}$` does not just non-greedily match the last tab until the end of line, but rather all tabs like in OPs problem.

Comment: @user1717828 the non-greedy operator does not overwrite the fact that the expression is still read and processed left-to-right. When you say `.*` it means at this point match anything and then go back trying to satisfy further conditions (if any). The non-greedy `.{-}` means match the least possible, starting from nothing, until the further conditions (again if any) are satisfied. Now back to your expression: first match the first tab you find on the line, and then anything as least as possible until the next condition which is end of line. So the first tab to end of the line will be matched.

Comment: @user1717828 In other words, think always left to right. So to reach the last tab we need to move the match to the end and then go back. Example to do what you want: `/.*\zs\t.*` which means anything first and this will move to the end. Then go back trying to find a tab. This will be the last tab. Start from before this tab (`\zs`) and match it plus anything else left.

Comment: @sidyll Oh, man!  That from-the-end search is great!  Just what I needed. Thanks!